# Python 3.6.4 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'

Tags: python, installation, text-mining, word-cloud

First of all, this is not a duplicate. I tried every single answers in similar wordcloud import errors. I installed it with pip (checked the right working directory), I tried to install a third party package from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud) and copy that to my current working directory, I tried it with pip install wordcloud and nothing worked. I'm still having;

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'

And when I tried to install it with conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud=1.8.1 I got;

C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud=1.8.1
Solving environment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

- seaborn
- wordcloud=1.8.1 -> python_abi=3.6[build=*_cp36m] -> pypy[version='<0a0']
  Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

And when I use the command in jupyter cell I get this;
[image]

I really need to install this package. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open Anaconda terminal and use one of these following commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 wordcloud
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 wordcloud
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 wordcloud
```

Comment: First option worked for me. Thanks and God bless

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working in Jupyter Notebooks and VS Code after installing wordcloud.

The following command can be used to install wordcloud

```
pip install wordcloud
```

After installation, import wordcloud using the code

```
from wordcloud.wordcloud import WordCloud
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```bash
pip install wordcloud
```

It worked for me.